# How to have a global code for all ajax errors in the html page?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
$.ajax({    
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
})
```

I don't want to have error block in each and every ajax call I have. 
I want some global code which will be called by default whenever an error is encountered in any ajax call within the page.

An easy solution will be something like:

```
$.ajax({
    error: error_call
});

function error_call(){  
}
```

Comment: Remove the `()` from `error: error_call()` and you're good to go

Comment: @Andreas yeah sorry that was a typo. I just wanted to know is there any other way to do that .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use global [`jQuery.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) or [`.ajaxError()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/).

> *Note: Global callback functions should be set with their respective
>   global Ajax event handler methods — .ajaxStart(), .ajaxStop(),
>   .ajaxComplete(), .ajaxError(), .ajaxSuccess(), .ajaxSend() — rather
>   than within the options object for $.ajaxSetup().*

---

**Example**:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, request, settings) {
     $("#msg").append("<li>Error requesting page " + settings.url + "</li>");
});
```

Comment: .ajaxError() looks good . What about jQuery.ajaxSetup() how to use that for error is it like :
$.ajaxSetup({ error:error_call});

Comment: @kaushikgandhi: _"Note: Global callback functions should be set with their respective global Ajax event handler methods — .ajaxStart(), .ajaxStop(), .ajaxComplete(), .ajaxError(), .ajaxSuccess(), .ajaxSend() — rather than within the options object for $.ajaxSetup()."_